# Error while using getResourceValue:forKey method in NSURL

Tags: iphone

I am trying to fetch the file size attribute from a NSURL object by passing it getResourceValue:forKey method. Here is the code i am writing:

```
NSURL *samplePath = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/Abhinav/Test/abhi.pdf"];
[samplePath getResourceValue:&name forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error===%@",error);
NSLog(@"name===%@",name);
```

But i am getting following error:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to get the file size of a local file, see [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager?language=occ)

For example, to get the size of a file: `int size = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:@"/Users/Abhinav/Test/abhi.pdf" error:NULL] fileSize];` should work (and will set `size` to `0` if the file does not exist, or is not readable).

Answer (score 6):

What type is `name` in your example?  You should be passing in the address of the variable where you want the size to be stored:

```
NSURL *samplePath = [[NSURL alloc initWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/Abhinav/Test/abhi.pdf"];
NSNumber *fileSizeBytes;
[samplePath getResourceValue:&fileSizeBytes forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error===%@",error); NSLog(@"size of file in bytes ===%@",fileSizeBytes);
```